# Best method to send information from Silverlight to Torque?

Tags: c#, silverlight, networking, torque3d

I'm programming a terrain generator for a sandbox game called Blockland. The generator is in Silverlight 5, and the game uses Torque 3D. What I need to do is send a list of strings from the site to the program, with approval from both sides. What would be the easiest method of doing this?

Comment: What did you already try (or do you maybe have some source code for us...)?

Comment: The problem is I don't know what TO try. I just need to send a few strings in series from a website to a game on the same computer.